# How to update table when subsquery returns zero row

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello I have table of users and subscriptions.

I want to set event for subscription table once in day to update expired status when today date is greater than EndDate (See Table Below) For every line in subscription table.

```
UPDATE subscription SET status=expired WHERE EndDate>TODAY
```

And Want to Set event to update user table status to expired if there no rows found in given sub query because while login user i am only checking user status not check subscription table as it will take load on mysql database. Want set expiry on all users at night to update table base EndDate

```
UPDATE userstable SET status=expired WHERE IN (SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE status=active AND userid=1)
```

--------Users Table------

```
userid,fname,lname,email,status
1,john,jacob,jjj@email.com,active
2,shelly,warden,shelly@mail.com,active
```

-------Subscription Table------

```
id,planID,userID,startDate,EndDate,Status
1,TRIAL,1,01/08/2020,07/08/2020,active 
2,MONTHLY,2,03/08/2020,02/09/2020,active
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sure will add sql code to create tables

Comment: ...and inserts... and desired result...and best efforts to date

Comment: Why do you want an update when the subquery has no results and is put into the where clause?

Comment: I want to check that all subscription plan for that user are expired so that i can update user status to expired. Below sub query should not return any value so that all plan for that user are expired. I want to run for all user to check status for each users.
    SELECT * FROM subscription WHERE status=active AND userid=1

Answer (score 0):

I got answer to it..

```
UPDATE users SET status='expired' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * WHERE users.id=subscriptions.userID AND subscriptions.status='active')
```

it updates user table if there is not active plan for that user.